# C segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, command-line-arguments, tokenize

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int numExperiment=1;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char* experiments[20];
    int data[10][20];
    char* input;
    char* endof = "***END***";

    do {
        input=fgets(input, 20, stdin);

        if (numExperiment%2 != 0) {
            experiments[numExperiment-1]=strdup(input);
        }
        else {
            int k=0;
            while ((data[k][numExperiment-1]=strsep(&input, " ") !=NULL)) {
               k++;
            }
        }

        numExperiment++;
    } while (strcmp(input, endof)!=0);
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote this code and it compiles without issue but when I run it I keep getting this error:
"Segmentation Fault: 11".

What this code is supposed to do is read a file and put all data on odd lines to one array and data on even lines on 2d arrays. I'm using command line redirection to read the file.

If anyone could point me in the right direction on how to correct this, that'd be great.

EDIT 1: I made a changes suggested below regarding allocating memory and fgets but i'm still getting segmentation fault 11.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 1000

int numExperiment=1;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    char* experiments[20];

    int data[10][20];
    char* input=malloc(N);
    char* endof="***END***\n";


    do {




        if (fgets(input, N, stdin) == NULL) break;


        if (numExperiment%2 != 0) {
        experiments[numExperiment-1]=strdup(input);
        }

        else {
            int k=0;
            while ((data[k][numExperiment-1]=strsep(&input, " ") !=NULL)) {
                k++;
            }


        }


        numExperiment++;



    } while ((fgets(input, N, stdin) != NULL) && (strcmp(input, endof)!=0));

    free(input);




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: need to allocate space for `input` before writing into it..

Comment: You either need to use `malloc` to allocate a pointer to some memory for `input` (which has no valid pointer in it currently), or declare `input` to be statically defined space, e.g., `char input[20];`.

Answer (score 1):

No allocated memory @amdixon

```
// char* input;
#define N 1000
char* input = malloc(N);
do {
   ...
} while (strcmp(input, endof)!=0);
free(input);
```

Bad use of `fgets()`

```
do {
  // input=fgets(input, 20, stdin);
  if (fgets(input, N, stdin) == NULL) break;
   ...
} while (strcmp(input, endof)!=0);
```

Likely wrong `endof` string.

```
// char* endof="***END***";
char* endof = "***END***\n";  // Add \n for `fgets()`
```

Suggest `do while` re-write

```
while (fgets(input, N, stdin) != NULL) && strcmp(input, endof)!=0) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, first of all, could you tell me what #define N 1000 does? I'm completely new to C, sorry. Second, I made all the changes you suggested but i'm still getting the same error as last time.

Comment: `#define N 1000` is a pre-processor macro.  Is does a text substitution, where ever `N` appears, by itself, it is replaced with `1000`.

Comment: Suggest in your lasted edit 1) Remove `if (fgets(input, N, stdin) == NULL) break;` 2) Replace `do {` with `while ((fgets(input, N, stdin) != NULL) && (strcmp(input, endof)!=0)) {` 3) Replace `} while ((fgets(input, N, stdin) != NULL) && (strcmp(input, endof)!=0));` with `}`. 4) May want to add a test after `k++` like `if(k >= 10) break;` to prevent `k` from getting too large.  5) I have no idea what `strsep()` does.  6) May a test after `numExperiment++;` to insure it does not get >= 20  7) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
char* input;
input=fgets(input, 20, stdin);
```

You have declared `input`, but not allocated memory for it.

Do either

```
char input[20];
```

or

```
char * input;
input = malloc(20);
```